# Composition class; using super or sub?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's consider two classes, `SuperClass`, and `SubClass` which extends it:

```
Class SuperClass{
    int superDataMember;
}

Class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    int subDataMember;
}
```

I need to have another `CompositeClass` class that may use super or sub composition depending on some criteria. My question is: Should I use

1. An instance of `SuperClass` inside `CompositeClass`

   - Thus, I can use either `SuperClass` instance or `SubClass` instance.
   - But how will methods accessing `subDataMember` behave if the accessed instance is of `SuperClass`?
   - Maybe an `instanceOf` check may work at the beginning of each method?

     ```
     Class CompositeClass {
         private SuperClass sc;

         public getSuperDataMember () {// some code}
         public getSubDataMember () {
         if (this.sc instanceOf SubClass)
             // some code
         }
     }
     ```
2. An instance of `SubClass` inside `CompositeClass`

   - Thus, I will lose the ability to access `SuperClass` instances!

     ```
     Class CompositeClass {
         private SubClass sc;

         public getSuperDataMember () {// some code}
         public getSubDataMember () {// some code
         }
     }
     ```
3. Implement two versions of `CompositeClass`, the first is `SuperCompositeClass` with an instance of `SuperClass` and the second `SubCompositeClass` that extends the first with an instance of `SubClass`!

Comment: Just follow the rules of inheritance and composition. If classes have "is a" relationship, then inheritance. If classes have "has a" relationship then composition.

Comment: Dear @JunedAhsan, it's not that simple in this specific case!

Comment: It depends how complicate we can make things by designing our classes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Mind that a `SubClass` is also a `SuperClass` so you won't lose the ability to access the component as a `SuperClass` like you pointed out.

In addition there is a third option, using parametric polymorphism:

```
class CompositeClass<T extends SuperClass>
{
  private T component;
  ...
}
```

So that you can adapt it to the specific situation. This will require you to override additional methods if not provided by the interface of `SuperClass` though.

Comment: By "An instance of SubClass inside CompositeClass", I mean that I cannot create an instance of `CompositeClass` with an instance of `SuperClass`, though as you mention, I can still access `SubClass` data members that are obtained by inheritance from `SuperClass`.

Comment: And in parametric polymorphism, I think I have to provide an instanceOf Check. Aren't I?

Comment: He proposed that your CompositeClass will have type `T` as for component type. That way you can choose which type `T` to use: super or/and sub types. You can use instanceOf if you need to.

Comment: 95% of the times `instanceof` can be replaced with a better design. Actual in a perfect world you won't need to use it unless in very specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me from your problem like your two classes might be better as siblings implementing an abstract class's methods than as a parent child relationship. This allows you to easily use polymorphism, using instanceOf if need be. A parent child relationship is most purely used when the child needs to retain all information and functionality of the parent.